# cannot convert 'std::array<float, 6ul>' to 'float' in initialization

Tags: c++

I encountered this code. It compiles on windows. (QT with MSVC2017 kit) But it didn't in Linux (QT with gcc 4.9.3)

I've read up on template array, the template function, parameter packing. I understand them individually but I am having a difficult time to put them all together to figure out how 
`util::make_array<6>(1.0f)`
in the last line is interpreted as a float. Assuming I was on the right direction.

```
namespace util { // @util
    namespace detail
    {
        template <typename T, std::size_t...Is>
        std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> make_array(const T& value, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        {
            return { { (static_cast<void>(Is), value)... } };
        }
    }

    template <std::size_t N, typename T>
    std::array<T, N> make_array(const T& value)
    {
        return detail::make_array(value, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
    }
}

std::array<float, 6> c_array {{ util::make_array< 6 >(0.1f) }}; //<- error here, "cannot convert 'std::array<float, 6ul>' to 'float' in initialization"
```

The error is on the last line:
"cannot convert 'std::array' to 'float' in initialization"

Comment: Looks like a bug.  It compiles in 5.1 after removing the inner curly braces: https://godbolt.org/z/qsNMj4

Comment: fwiw, GCC 4 is outdated, the latest version is GCC 9, and oldest supported version is GCC 7.

Comment: Okay, thanks! That certainly makes sense, since MSVC2017 certainly is at least c++14 compliant.